# find the rank of a matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

let $A$ be a $5 \times 4$ matrix with real entries such that the space of all solutions of the linear system $AX^t=[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]^t$ is given by 
$$\{\;[1+2s,2+3s, 3+4s]^t : s \in R\;\}.$$

What is the rank of A?

Comment: Welcome to StackExchange! Although people here will help with homework, they won't do it for you. Posts that do not show any effort tend to be poorly received and left unanswered. Can you please share your thoughts on the problem and explain what you've tried?

Comment: Your solution set seems to suggest that it should be a $5\times 3$ matrix.

Answer (score 0):

There seem to be an incorrectness in your question. As you may know multiplying a $5\times 4$ matrix with a vector of dimension $4$ ($4\times 1$) will give you a vector with dimension $5$ ($5\times 1$). Now you have mentioned that the matrix is $5\times 4$ and to satisfy the given system your $X$ should be a $4\times 1$. Else the matrix should be $5\times 3$. Is there a typo somewhere?